# No message found under code 'user.title' for locale 'en_US

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I'm trying to add following code to existing jsp page, but I'm getting 'No message found under code 'trace' for locale 'en_US' error.

```
<td valign="top"><spring:message code="trace" /></td>
<td valign="top"><form:input type="textbox" id="noOfTrace"
class="textbox" path="branch.noOfTrace"
value="${installation.getBranch().getNoOfTrace()}" />
</td>
```

Can anyone help? Also I'm not aware where this code="trace" will refer.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to find out about ResourceBundle. For any application supporting internationalization, it requires the capability of resolving text messages for different locales. These come from properties file called a resource bundle.You will have separate properties file for each locale.You place these properties file in class-path and configure their name and location this the spring xml. Something like below. So messages.properties will be containing key value pair with keyname you will be using to refer to the text in that locale.

```
 <bean id="messages" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename">
            <value>messages</value>
        </property> </bean>
```

In your case,"trace" is a key in the properties file  ,and its trying to find the value for that to print using "spring:messages" tag. Check below:

1. Please check your spring config xml to see resourcebundle correctly configured.

2.See which properties file its referring to and Whether its present in classpath .

3.Check whether it has key named "trace"

You can read online about how to use spring resourcebundle and you will get more idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to configure internationalization by configuration class.

It is mandatory to define the place where your messages will be stored.

```
@Bean
public ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {
    ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasename("messages");

    return messageSource;
}
```

Also try to define the default locale. You can do this like below

```
@Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
        AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver localeResolver = new AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver();
        localeResolver.setDefaultLocale(Locale.US);

        return localeResolver;
    }
```

Make sure the message with the key you are looking for is in the "messages" file